# Logical read when use Offset in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, statistics, offset-fetch

When I execute this script

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS [ROW_NO] 
FROM 
    vwTblTest 
WHERE 
    ([Factor] >= 139501 AND [Factor] < 139507) AND 
    ...
ORDER BY 
    [Date] DESC 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;
```

The `vwTblTest` is a view that join two table like this :

```
SELECT
    [tbl1].*,
    [tbl2].*
FROM
    [tbl1] 
    INNER JOIN
    [tbl2] ON ([tbl2].[Factor] = [tbl1].[Tbl1Factor] 
           AND [tbl2].[ID] = [tbl1].[Tbl2ID]) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (select Reference, 
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(COUNT(Reference), 0) = 0 THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END 
              AS HasReference 
     FROM [tbl3] 
     GROUP BY Reference
    ) reference ON reference.Reference = [tbl2].ID
```

`tbl1` contains about 9 million records, and it has a partition on `Factor` field.
If `tbl2` contains 25 or more records every thing is fine, But when `tbl2` contains less than 25 records statistic report show a lot of logical read to execute script.

Column `[Date]` is from `tbl1`. For cross checking with the plans:

```
tbl1 : doc_LetterInstances 
tbl2 : doc_Letters 
tbl3 : doc_LetterReferences
```

Statistics :

> Scan count 1, **logical reads 12754432**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Execution Plan :
[image: Execution plan of script 1]

When I change script like bellow statistic report show normal logical reads. **`OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY`** was removed.

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT 
    *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS [ROW_NO] 
FROM 
    vwTblTest 
WHERE 
    ([Factor] >= 139501 AND [Factor] < 139507) AND 
    ...
ORDER BY 
    [Date] DESC
```

Statistics :

> Scan count 1, **logical reads 45**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Execution Plan :
[image: Execution plan of script 2]

**What is wrong in my query?**

Comment: Can you show execution plan?

Comment: Please give your actual query and details about the table sizes and structure of the three tables involved.

Comment: Which version are you on?

Comment: @MartinSmith Execution plan was added

Comment: Yes I saw that - but that shows the situation is in fact significantly different from your original question - which indicates only a single table is involved. Presumably the difference is because you are getting a different join strategy.

Comment: So can you show the `SELECT` query behind `doc_vwTblTest` and the definitions of the relevant tables including indexes?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik SQL Server 2012

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ actual query was added

Comment: @MartinSmith the only difrence between this queries is 'OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY', 
I think the query behind 'vwTblTest' not important.

Comment: @MartinSmith `vwTableTest` query was added.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `[Date]` from tbl1.
tbl1 : doc_LetterInstances
tbl2 : doc_Letters
tbl3 : doc_LetterReferences

Comment: Thnx, I added the info in the question.